# Pegar o Id do cliente de uma linha selecionada do DataTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-datatables

Como pegar o Id do cliente de um `DataTable` sendo que essa coluna está oculta ? 
Quando eu clicar na linha do `DataTable` vou precisar desse ID para exibir em outra View com os detalhes do Cliente.

Tenho o seguinte código

```
  @model IEnumerable<Dominio.Entidade.TBCliente>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CLIENTE";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Administrativo/Views/Shared/_AdministrativoLayout.cshtml";
}


<table id="tblCLiente" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-striped small">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NOME</th>
            <th>TIPO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var table = $("#tblCLiente").DataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "scrollY": "50vh",
                "scrollCollapse": true,

                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Exibir _MENU_ registros por páginas",
                    "zeroRecords": "NÃO LOCALIZADO",
                    "info": "Exibir de _PAGE_ até _PAGE_",
                    "infoEmpty": "REGISTRO NÃO LOCALIZADO!",
                    "infoFiltered": " (de um total de_MAX_ registros.)",

                },
                "sAjaxSource": "BuscarCliente",
                "aoColumns": [
                                { "sName": "TBCLIENTEID", "mData": "TBCLIENTEID", "bVisible": false },
                                { "sName": "NMCLIENTE", "mData": "NMCLIENTE" },
                                { "sName": "TPCLIENTE", "mData": "TPCLIENTE" }
                ],
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });



            $('#tblCLiente tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
                else {
                    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }
            });

            $('#button').click(function () {
                table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
            });

            table.$('tr').click(function () {
                var data = table.fnGetData(this);
                alert(data);
        });

        });

    </script>
}
```

**ACTION**

```
public JsonResult BuscarCliente()
    {
        string echo = Request.Params["sEcho"].ToString();
        string iColumns = Request.Params["iColumns"].ToString();
        string sColumns = Request.Params["sColumns"].ToString();
        int iDisplayStart = int.Parse(Request.Params["iDisplayStart"].ToString());
        int iDisplayLength = int.Parse(Request.Params["iDisplayLength"].ToString());
        string mDataProp_0 = Request.Params["mDataProp_0"].ToString();
        string sSearch = Request.Params["sSearch"].ToString();
        string iSortCol_0 = Request.Params["iSortCol_0"].ToString();
        string sSortDir_0 = Request.Params["sSortDir_0"].ToString();
        string iSortingCols = Request.Params["iSortingCols"].ToString();
        string bSortable_0 = Request.Params["bSortable_0"].ToString();
        int regExibir = iDisplayLength;
        int startExibir = iDisplayStart;

        List<TBCliente> lClienteFiltrado = new List<TBCliente>();
        List<TBCliente> lTotalCliente = _IRepositorio.ListarCliente();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sSearch))
        {
            lClienteFiltrado = lTotalCliente.Where(x => x.NMCLIENTE.ToUpper().Contains(sSearch.ToUpper())).ToList<TBCliente>();
        }
        else
        {
            lClienteFiltrado = lTotalCliente;
        }

        if (iDisplayStart > lClienteFiltrado.Count)
            startExibir = 0;
        if (iDisplayStart + iDisplayLength > lClienteFiltrado.Count)
            regExibir = lClienteFiltrado.Count - startExibir;

        if (sSortDir_0 == "asc")
        {
            if (iSortCol_0 == "0")
                lClienteFiltrado = lClienteFiltrado.OrderBy(x => x.TBCLIENTEID).ToList<TBCliente>();
            if (iSortCol_0 == "1")
                lClienteFiltrado = lClienteFiltrado.OrderBy(x => x.NMCLIENTE).ToList<TBCliente>();
            if (iSortCol_0 == "2")
                lClienteFiltrado = lClienteFiltrado.OrderBy(x => x.TPCLIENTE).ToList<TBCliente>();
        }
        else
        {
            if (iSortCol_0 == "0")
                lClienteFiltrado = lClienteFiltrado.OrderByDescending(x => x.TBCLIENTEID).ToList<TBCliente>();
            if (iSortCol_0 == "1")
                lClienteFiltrado = lClienteFiltrado.OrderByDescending(x => x.NMCLIENTE).ToList<TBCliente>();
            if (iSortCol_0 == "2")
                lClienteFiltrado = lClienteFiltrado.OrderByDescending(x => x.TPCLIENTE).ToList<TBCliente>();
        }

        var Resultado = new
        {
            sEcho = echo,
            iTotalRecords = lTotalCliente.Count,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = lClienteFiltrado.Count,
            //iDisplayLength = 10,
            aaData = lClienteFiltrado.ToList<TBCliente>().GetRange(startExibir, regExibir)
        };
        return Json(Resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Os dados da datatable estão vindo como? Paginado pelo servidor? Você gera tudo no HTML e depois converte em datatable? Existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso e o modo como a tabela é gerada pode influenciar.

Comment: Erick o processamento está sendo feito no servidor, eu adicionei na pergunta a Action que retorna os dados para o DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, uma maneira de fazer isso é utilizar **fnGetData**

Para isso depois de declarar sua table você declara o evento de get data para cara linha (row) da sua tabela.

```
table.$('tr').click( function () {
    var data = table.fnGetData( this );
    // a variavel data vai conter ou um array ou objeto contendo todos os dados da sua row
  } );
```

Documentação oficial http://datatables.net/api#fnGetData

**Editado**

Outra coisa, o mais correto seria você fazer

```
var table = $("#tblCLiente").DataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true, ....
```

E não chamar depois o **var table = $("#tblCLiente").DataTable()** é como se você tivesse recriando o DataTable.

Comment: Obrigado Erick mas não funciona

Comment: @AdrianoCordeiro Da algum erro? Retorna vazio? O que acontece quando você usa o fnGetData?

Comment: Tem razão Erick sobre a variável table eu já alterei, porém estou na mesma, ou seja: Não da erro e nem retorna nada, simplesmente qdo clico na linha do DataTable não acontece nada.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução e fic ai pra quem passar pela mesma situação que eu, a solução foi adicionar o valor do id cliente para o atributo `"id"` para do parâmetro `"rowCallback":` da requisição ajax:

```
           "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
                $(row).attr("id", data.TBCLIENTEID);
            },
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"ódigo aqui
```

e depois recuperar no click da linha:

```
$('#tblCLiente tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var id = this.id;
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
        });

        $('#button').click(function () {
            table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
        });
```